# get number of rows where certain column is not NA for different categories of another column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `qq`. Following is the `dput`

```
    structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(NA, NA, 4.7, NA, 5), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
NA, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4), 
    Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Species = c("a", 
    "a", "b", "b", "b")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000011c90788>)

> qq
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2       a
2:           NA          NA          1.4         0.2       a
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       b
4:           NA         3.1          1.5         0.2       b
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       b
```

I want to get number of rows for each category of column `Species` such that column `Sepal.Length` is not NA. Final result will look like following (see new column `no_rows`)

```
> qq

       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    no_rows
    1:           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2       a      0
    2:           NA          NA          1.4         0.2       a      0
    3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       b      2 
    4:           NA         3.1          1.5         0.2       b      2
    5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       b      2
```

I did the following

```
qq[, no_rows:= nrow(qq[is.na(Sepal.Length) == F, ]), .(Species)]
```

But it is not working. Can somebody give me an efficient solution for a data.table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We group by 'Species', get the `sum` of logical index (`!is.na(Sepal.Length)`) and assign (`:=`) the output to create the 'no_rows'.

```
qq[, no_rows := sum(!is.na(Sepal.Length)) , by = Species]
qq
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species no_rows
#1:           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2       a       0
#2:           NA          NA          1.4         0.2       a       0
#3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       b       2
#4:           NA         3.1          1.5         0.2       b       2
#5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       b       2
```

Comment: what if i have to group by 2 columns? Say `Species` and `Petal Width`?

Comment: @user3664020, go through the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).